# Oracle columns were missed while fetching data to CSV file using || in select query

Tags: oracle, csv

We are trying to fetch data from oracle to CSV file through oracle spool.
But all columns were not fetched some columns were missing. Using below query

```
select colm1||'"~"'||colm2||'"~"'||...colm159||'"~"'|| from table;
```

It fetched only few columns.
While using same `select` query separated with `','` fetching all columns
eg: `colm1,colm2,colm3...colm159 from table;`

Please help me to sort this out

Thanks

Comment: If you concatenate all the columns like that your result set has a single column which is subject to the standard Oracle limit for column size in SQL: 4000 characters

Answer (score 0):

Many IDEs such as SQL Developer support CSV export with a right-click menu but you can do it in SQL*Plus like this:

```
SQL> set colsep '~'
SQL> set echo off
SQL> set pages 0
SQL> set line 5000 -- or whatever is enough up to 32767 
SQL> spool your_table.tsv
SQL> select /* csv */ * from your_table;
SQL> spool off
```

I recommend using the `.tsv` file extension. If you use `.csv` Excel assumes comma separation whereas with `.tsv` we get a nice dialog box to specify the separator.

If your longest line is more than 32k characters you'll need a different approach.

Comment: I have tried with colsep, the problem with colsep is getting extra spaces in the fetched data. I need a solution to avoid spaces or to fetch all columns using || in select query.  I even tried setting trim On to avoid spaces. Thankyou